# Stringstream vs. type casting in C++

Tags: c++, casting, stringstream

How does using `stringstream` to extract an integer value from a string differ from simply using explicit value casting to change the type?

Example:

```
string a = "1234";
int x;
x= int (a);
```

vs.

```
string a = "1234";
int x;
stringstream (a) >> x;
```

Comment: Well for one thing `x= int (a);` won't work.

Comment: My bad, I had mixed up the data types.

Comment: @Marcel If you meant something different, you should change your question too...

Comment: @Marcel deviantfan is right, the example code does not match your question and without an update it's just nonsense.

Comment: As you noted, the first example will not work. As I had managed to misunderstand an article, I was under the impression that one could change string types to integer types, which was of course incorrect. Therefore, the question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, major difference is that:

```
string a = "1234";
int x;
x= int (a);
```

does not compile, there is no conversion from std::string to int. Modern way to convert std::string to int is to use [stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function, but be carefull with it because it will throw for "x1234" but will hapilly parse: "1234x".

Comment: Could you explain why it will treat "x1234" and "1234x" differently?

Comment: @Marcel its all in the link I provided, `...takes as many characters as possible to form a valid base-n (where n=base) integer number `, and throws std::invalid_argument `if no conversion could be performed`.